# what is the most efficient way to compare two strings?

Tags: c#, string, compare

Just like this page at stakeoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/620144/list

I want to compare two strings and found which parts have been modified.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a variant of the [Hirschberg's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirschberg%27s_algorithm). Anyway dynamic programming is the way to go, consult any standard algorithm reference book.